# Splitting one row into two rows

Tags: sql

How do I split one row into two in SQL?

Let's say I have the columns

```
Name, Time, Model
```

and I have a row such as `'Nick', 1:00, 2010`.  Also Model can either be 2010 or 2012.

How can I make it such that I'll have

```
'Nick', NULL, 2012
'Nick', 1:00, 2010
```

instead of just one row.  Basically, I need to do something like this for all rows in my table, where we list the model that's not listed as a new row with a NULL value under the date section.

Thanks!

Comment: Sample data please. Not clear for me, your question.

Comment: your model is comma separated years?

Comment: Maybe do a `UNION` of the table into itself?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  name,
        CASE q.id WHEN 1 THEN time END time,
        CASE q.id WHEN 1 THEN model ELSE '2012' END model
FROM    (
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2
        ) q (id)
CROSS JOIN
        mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also working. If required, you can add more years to the value list like (2011),(2013) to get expected results for those years as well.

**[Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83c1e/27)** (Example data types may be different to yours)

```
select name, 
       case when t1.model = t2.year then t1.time end time,
       year 
from temp t1
   cross join (values (2010),(2012)) as t2(year)
order by t2.year desc

| NAME |     TIME | YEAR |
--------------------------
| Nick | 01:00:00 | 2010 |
| Nick |   (null) | 2012 |
```

Comment: This is nice but I can see this being a performance hit since it's using a cross-join (I'm actually trying to do something with an even larger dataset).  I guess I'll just try it out for myself and see what happens.